# Get path from URL

Tags: php, url

Looking for a way of getting the path from an URL in PHP:

I want to take: `http://example.com/hurrdurr`

And make it: `hurrdurr`

I only want the text after `.com/`

Can i do this with trim?

Comment: [`trim`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) is for removing whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract part from URL for a query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080530/extract-part-from-url-for-a-query-string)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the information you want.

For instance:

```
$url = "http://twitter.com/pwsdedtch";
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH); // gives "/pwsdedtech"
$pathWithoutSlash = substr($path, 1); // gives "pwsdedtech"
```

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this a decade later, if you have a URL with a trailing slash, you may want to consider using PHP's [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function instead of `substr`. For instance: `trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');`

Comment: @Xhynk, keep in mind that `trim` removes characters from both ends of the string, which may not be what you want. `substr`’s extremely predictable behaviour might make it less likely to cause surprises.

Comment: @zneak, maybe [ltrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim) is a preferred option in this case since you can specify the characters to trim on the left, ie `ltrim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');`

Answer (score 8):

**For this particular case** you could also use "basename" for your purposes.

```
$var='http://twitter.com/pwsdedtch';    
echo basename($var);
// pwsdedtech
```