# Strip the last part off a url

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, parse-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extract last part of a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983943/extract-last-part-of-a-url)

I have a url like this:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/product/SportingGoods/Cookware/1/B000YEU9NA/Coleman-Family-Cookset
```

I want extract just the product name off the end "Coleman-Family-Cookset"

When I use parse_url and print_r I end up with the following:

```
Array (
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.domain.co.uk
    [path] => /product/SportingGoods/Cookware/1/B000YEU9NA/Coleman-Family-Cookset
)
```

How do I then trim "Coleman-Family-Cookset" off the end?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983943/extract-last-part-of-a-url

Comment: Ok I've done it like this: ''$lastPart = parse_url($url);
$lastPart = $lastPart[path]; 
$lastPart = explode("/", $lastPart);
echo $lastPart[6];'' any improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/product/SportingGoods/Cookware/1/B000YEU9NA/Coleman-Family-Cookset';
$url = explode('/', $url);
$last = array_pop($url);
echo $last;
```

Answer (score 7):

All the answers above works but all use unnecessary arrays and regular expressions, you need a position of last `/` which you can get with [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and than you can extract string with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
substr( $url, 0, strrpos( $url, '/'));
```

<sub>You'll maybe have to add `+/- 1` after `strrpos()`</sub>

This is much more effective solution than using `preg_*` or `explode`, all work though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
preg_match('/([^\/]*)$/', $url, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

[Test](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%28%5B%5E/%28%5B%5E%5C/%5D%2a%29%24&input=http://www.domain.co.uk/product/SportingGoods/Cookware/1/B000YEU9NA/Coleman-Family-Cookset%0A)

Answer (score 1):

You have the path variable(from the array as shown above). 
Use the following:

```
$tobestripped=$<the array name>['path']; //<<-the entire path that is
$exploded=explode("/", $tobestripped);
$lastpart=array_pop($exploded);
```

Hope this helps.