# Get a part of a string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract part from URL for a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080530/extract-part-from-url-for-a-query-string)
>   [how do i parse url php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-url-php)

I have a string like this one:

`http://twitter.com/what/`

How can I get the `what` part ?

Basically I want to get the last part of a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "http://twitter.com/what/";
echo basename($url);
```

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = "http://twitter.com/what/";

$parts = parse_url($url);

$what = substr($parts['path'], 1, strlen($parts['path']) - 2);
```

Comment: thanks, I thought I needed regex or something like that :)

Comment: It would've been an easy regex to write... or to search for and copy.

Comment: @Dan: In a second thought, this won't get exactly the required string. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using preg_match

```
<?php

if (preg_match('/http:\/\/([^\/]*)\/(.*)/', "http://twitter.com/what/", $m)) {
    $domain = $m[1]; // will contain 'twitter.com'
    $path = $m[2]; // will contain 'what/'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://twitter.com/what/";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$parts = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));

echo $parts[0]; // output: what
```

If the URL will contain other parts in the path. E.g. `http://twitter.com/what/else/`. Then the `else` part will be on the second index of the array, and you can access it like this `$parts[1]`.